# Регулярка, BBCode на JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Собственно я написал код, который выделенный текст обрамляет в бб-теги:

```
[list][/list]
```

Вопрос таков:

Как выделенный текст находящийся между бб-тегами `[list][/list]` и находящийся в переменной **s** раздраконить, чтобы каждая новая строка начиналась с `[*]`

Короче для тех кто не понял, показываю, было так:

```
[list]васек купил
себе огромную
хренатень[/list]
```

а должно стать так:

```
[list][*]васек купил
[*]себе огромную
[*]хренатень[/list]
```

Вот небольшой код по этому поводу, как его доработать?

```
var regex = new RegExp('([\r\n]+)', 'gi');
s = s.replace(regex, '$1[*]') + '\r\n';
```

Comment: не ужели так сложно? о_О

Answer (score 2):

А зачем регулярные выражения?

```
s = "[*]" + s.split("\n").join("\n[*]");
```

Ну или

```
s = "[*]" + s.replace(/\n/gm, "\n[*]");
```

---

Чтобы побороть проблемы пустых строк, можно попробовать вот так:

```
s = "[*]" + s.split("\n").filter(function(e) { return e; }).join("\n[*]");
```

Comment: А перед первым элементом списка? :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: наверняка что-нибудь наподобие `s/^|\n/[*]\0/gm`, но я решил не думать и добавить вручную. Угадал?

Comment: Не-не-не. Как-то так надо это делать регексами:  

    text= text.replace(/(\[list\])(?![\\r\\n])|(\\n)(?!\[\/list\]/gi, "$1$2[*]");
Так не будет проблем на тексте:  

    [list]
    element 1
    element 2
    [/list]
На данный момент оба ответа из вопроса отдадут:      

    [list][*]
    [*]element 1
    [*]element 2
    [*][/list]
что не совсем корректно.

Comment: @ReinRaus: добавил альтернативное решение с фильтром -- вам оно не кажется понятнее? Тем более, в `s` нету `[list]`, там только content.

Comment: @ReinRaus автор привел конкретный пример и больше ничего не говорил :-) Вообще сам люблю делать так, чтобы "на все случаи жизни". Но иногда и нет.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = text.replace(/\n|^\[.*\]/g, function(data) {
    return data +'[*]';
});
```